Issue running streamlit in VScode / module 'streamlit' has no attribute 'title' error
I am creating a new streamlit app with the following:
import streamlit as st
st.title("Grid Generator")

I can import the streamlit module without error but then get the following when I run the second line:

AttributeError: module 'streamlit' has no attribute 'title'

I am using the correct python environment in VScode. (I am not an expert on using python in VScode so I have likely missed something here). I uninstalled and reinstalled streamlit with pip succcessfully and when I check the module version I get the following:
Successfully installed streamlit-1.33.0

PS C:\Users\dld\OneDrive - Equinor\python> streamlit version show
Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<frozen runpy>", line 198, in _run_module_as_main
      File "<frozen runpy>", line 88, in _run_code
      File "C:\Appl\my_env\Scripts\streamlit.exe\__main__.py", line 4, in <module>
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'streamlit.web'; 'streamlit' is not a package

the above message suggests that it is looking in the correct environment. Any insight into what is wrong with my set up?

Show the full error message. Also describe the way you executed the code.

Not sure what is going on with your re-install, but when I ran into the error you saw (different casing, though, I guess), it was because I was calling st.Title (note the invalid capital T).  Adding this comment in case there is anyone else who sees this error, it might be that.
